# JS/jQuery - get the type of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If for the sake of argument I'm applying a class to a `<p>` and an `<a>` and I then want to determine whether it was an `<a>` or a `<p>` that was clicked, is there a way to do it?

Example of intended use:

```
$(".selector").click(function(){
    element = $(this).whatElementWasClicked(); // return "a" or "p"
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$(".selector").click(function(event){ 
    var element = event.target.nodeName }
```

Answer (score 6):

`$(this).is("a")` , for example, will also work. This is useful if you're checking against a more complicated selector, not just a particular element type.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName) or [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName).

Comment: Rather than Mozilla doc, how 'bout the W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095 and http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-104682815

Comment: @OP: If you're wondering why there are two, don't worry about it, for elements (as opposed to attributes or text nodes), they'll have the same value. If you're using elements only, `tagName` will be more familiar to other people reading your code.

Comment: @TJCrowder I prefer the Mozilla docs because they usually have examples, cross browser compatibility info (where appropriate) _and_ links to the relevant specs.

Answer (score 2):

use tagName for getting the tag