# how to get type name using event?

Tags: jquery

can you please tell me how to get the type name from event.
It mean when user click button it show "Button".if it click div it show "div" or input field"

Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/W3xLT/

```
<button>test</button>
<div>test</div>
<input type="test">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).click(function(e){
        alert(e.target..attr())

    });    

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS/jQuery - get the type of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068516/js-jquery-get-the-type-of-element)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the target's [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) to get the element type

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
        alert(e.target.tagName);  
    });    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YVnNh/)

Note: Since you are binding the handler to the document object, it need not be done in a dom ready handler

Answer (score 1):

You can use tagName

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3xLT/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $(document).click(function(e){
        alert(e.target.tagName);            
    });    
});
```

You can use tagName to get the type if tagName is INPUT

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3xLT/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(document).click(function(e){        
        if(e.target.tagName != 'INPUT')
             alert(e.target.tagName);        
        else
            alert(e.target.type);        
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/W3xLT/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).click(function(e){
        alert(e.target.localName)

    });    

});
```